# Are moderators held accountable for behavior outside of Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, behavior

There is nothing in the [Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal) that indicates that a *user* of a Stack Exchange can be held accountable for their actions outside of the site.

For example, if a user was to make disparaging remarks against the site in *any* medium not related with Stack Exchange, they are not held accountable.

Moderators are, for lack of a better term, *different* from regular users:

- They have to abide by the [Moderator Agreement](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement) in addition to the Terms of Service
- They are listed on the about page of our sites
- They carry flair (the diamond) with our name on everything

While there is no *specific mention* of a code of conduct for behavior *outside* of the Stack Exchange sites, can a moderator's behavior outside the Stack Exchange sites be brought against them and affect their status as moderator?

Comment: What are you planning to do?

Comment: Well you are different from regular users, but still volunteers. If accountable, I'd say it's only to the community. That said, whatever you are planning to do, pics or it didn't happen.

Answer (score 12):

Shouldn't this bridge be crossed when we come to it?

One man's complaining about how things are done on Meta or SO are the other man's disparaging remarks.  Having a pre-defined set of rules for this doesn't feel right, and smacks of thought police. Don't forget - being a mod is a great honour and all, but they are still unpaid volunteers.

I say this stuff should be handled as it comes up. If anything does come up. As long as they're not obviously and badly harming the community, mods should be able to do and say whatever they want, wherever they want.

Answer (score 5):

If the team wanted to extract a promise of public non-disparagement from mods, the team would have extracted it. This leads me to believe that a moderator would have to mount a pretty spectacular public spectacle in which they abuse the SE trademarks and their moderator status all at once to attract unfavorable attention.

Comment: ... or start spreading rumours. Is it true that Jeff congregates weekly with all the mods via Skype to worship Satan?

Comment: @Pekka'sOrganicRepFarm No, it's not true. We don't include all the mods.

Comment: @Gilles so you can opt out on religious grounds? And I thought the man  had a *mission*.

Comment: @Pekka'sOrganicRepFarm No, it's Joel, over IRC, and to worship Set.

Comment: Ah, I was not invited there ...

Comment: @Paulo I think they don't trust the Cryptographers SE. They fear they could break their evil codes. Did you know that if you play the December data dump as a WAV file, you can hear Satanistic, no, Setist messages?

Comment: @casparOne are you sure it it's Set, and not Li(z)st?

Comment: You guys have been worshiping **Set** this whole time? Now my feelings are hurt, I thought you were worshiping **Seth**. Sheesh.